# how to make an if statement to check if my array is overflowing

Tags: c++

I want to make this code work where I'll make an programme where it will say if my char array has too much character and if the user input does not exceed my char array value it will display the user input my code is this

```
char string[20];
length = strlen(string);

std::cout << "enter input: ";

std::cin.width(20); 
std::cin >> string;
```

the output should display the user input if it's not exceeding the array value but if the input is exceeding it will display too much character

Comment: use `cin::getline` to read in up to x characters, or better yet, switch to using a `std::string` and don't limit the input to arbitrary amount.

Comment: Do you know what `std::string` is, how it works, and how to use it?

Comment: Forget everything you know about C-style strings and use `std::string`

Comment: Where are you learning C++ from? I must be an outdated source, using these kind of "C" style arrays for strings should no longer be necessary. As said use std::string which has been available since C++98... so it is not exactly a new thing

Comment: `length = strlen(string);` is just wrong (at least where it is placed). and cannot be used to check overflow anyway.

Comment: In current C++ there are a lot of things available to avoid running into array overruns. Also look at std::vector and [range based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: Also good sources to learn C++ from are a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C"). Or you can use  [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/). Also make sure to check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
And finally refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to learn how C++  is intended to be used.

Comment: @Clifford But it's the opposite, it just confirms why is `using namespace std;` a bad thing to do. This is even what namespaces are for, to allow names reuse without conflicts :)

Comment: What c++ standard are you using? C++20 added a `>>` overload for arrays that reads no more than 20 characters https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Comment: @Clifford I don't follow you. This is the whole purpose of namespaces. If you keep doing the old (C) way to find unique names despite having them enclosed in a namespace, then you don't understand what are namespaces and why you are using one. If I want to have a function `find()` or a class `string`, I no longer need to write `mylib_find()` and `mylib_string()` thanks to namespace isolation. But the right thing to do would be to define them in my own namespace. The whole purpose of namespaces was to avoid all the clutter we needed to avoid name conflicts and have the names we want available.

Comment: As long as you don't `using namespace whatever;`, you're guaranteed to be safe about conflicts between things defined in another namespace.

Comment: Ignore what Paul said.  If you have been programming in C++ for, oh say, 8 or more years, you can feel empowered to use C-style strings.  But before then, definitely use `std::string`, and never use C-style strings, or C-style arrays, or `new` or `new[]` or `malloc` or owning-raw pointers, or C-isms that are non-idiomatic C++.

Comment: @Clifford The thing is that it won't incur any error at all, exactly due to namespace encapsulation. This is the whole point, your claim about _"may introduce errors in later reuse and maintenance"_ is plain wrong. In the same lines, all decent libraries disagree with you. For example boost :) And your other claim about confusion is also wrong. I prefer to use a function with a clear and concise name, let's say `boost::bind()`, no matter that `std::bind()` also exists. It would have been a shame if boost had called it `boost::boost_bind()` for example.

Comment: @Fareanor you clearly insist on misunderstanding my point, now deleted in any case.  It is distracting from the original question, and just advice.  Choose good names _and_ use namespaces.  They are not mutually exclusive and `string` is an ill-advised name in defensive programming.  You are taking a language lawyer view, not a human factors view.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the line and test if it is the required length or not:

```
std::string line;

std::cout << "enter input: ";
std::cin >> line;

if (line.size() > 20)
{
   std::cout << "too many characters" << std::endl;
}
else
{
   std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @iqeufix if it's that good, reward the guy with an **accept** followed by an **upvote**. That's proper SO ethics.

Comment: This will ignore spaces, then start reading text, then stop at the first whitespace character.  Best to use `std::getline`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, string also has a lot of operations.
So you also should never use functions like strcmp, strcpy, strlen either.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "enter input: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    std::cout << "\n" << "Length of your input = " << input.length() << "\n";
    std::cout << "input = " << input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++20 replaced the old `<<` overload for pointers to `char` with an overload that has an actual array as argument:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, std::size_t N >

basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& operator>>( basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& st, CharT (&s)[N] );
```

See here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2.

It extracts not more than `N-1` characters from the stream (and inserts a null-terminator after the characters that were read).

If you want to know if there were more characters in the stream you can peek to see if the next character is a space, or whether the stream reached `eof`, thats the other two possibilities for extraction to stop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char x[3]{};
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << std::strlen(x) << "\n";
    std::cout << "entered string has max len of 2: " << (std::cin.peek()== ' ' || std::cin.eof()) ;
}
```

However, as others have mentioned, you should rather use `std::string`.